# Explicit call to destructor before longjmp/croak

Tags: c++, perl, setjmp

I'm writing a PERL XS interface to a C++ library. I need to call `croak` when the library throws an exception.

Doing it directly in the exception handler misses the call to the caught exception's destructor, as expected of a `longjmp` call. This is important, because the exception contains string members which won't get freed.

The obvious solution is to do the `croak` after the catch block, if an exception was caught, like this:

```
bool do_croak = false;
try {
    throw MyException();
} catch (MyException &e) {
    do_croak = true;
}
if (do_croak)
    croak(NULL);
```

But I'm wondering: Would it be enough to just explicitly call the caught exception's destructor just before the `longjmp`? Like this:

```
try {
    throw MyException();
} catch (MyException &e) {
    e.~MyException();
    croak(NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's almost impossible to use `longjmp` safely in a C++ program. Specifically:

> C++11 18.10/4: A `setjmp`/`longjmp` call pair has undefined behavior if replacing the `setjmp` and `longjmp` by `catch` and `throw` would invoke any non-trivial destructors for any automatic objects.

In this case, throwing an exception from `croak` would invoke the destructor of `e`, so calling `longjmp` from there would give undefined behaviour. Calling the destructor yourself just makes the behaviour even less defined.

Comment: Hmmm. But the "obvious approach" I mentioned (please see new code in updated question) should be sane, assuming only PODs outside the catch? (I'm using C++98/03)

Comment: @Irfy: I wouldn't call undefined behaviour "sane". If you mean that it's likely that most compilers will end up correctly destroying `e` despite the behaviour being undefined, then you may be right; but in my opinion relying on undefined behaviour is a very bad idea.

Comment: Perhaps you misunderstood which approach I meant. I meant the approach where the croak happens after the try-catch. Replacing croak with a catch there wouldn't cause any destructors to run, since e is already destroyed by the time. Or do you see undefined behavior there too?

Comment: @Irfy: Sorry, I didn't notice the change to the question. That is indeed well-defined *as long as* you meet the requirement that you don't jump out of the scope of anything with a non-trivial destructor. Of course, it's still very dangerous since there's no way to enforce that requirement.

Comment: Very well. I will then stick to my original approach.